# i am working on Alexa skill using java and Aws dynamo db. every time i enter data it is sending a user id as primary key can i remove that

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit, userid

this is the code and i want to remove the user id for in this ques

```
public Optional<String> getSlot(String key) {
    String value = null;
    Request request = input.getRequestEnvelope().getRequest();
    if (request instanceof IntentRequest) {
        IntentRequest intentRequest = (IntentRequest) request;
        value = intentRequest.getIntent().getSlots().get(key).getValue();
    }return Optional.ofNullable(value);
}
```

this is the other class to add notes

```
public void addUserNote(String newNote) {
    Map<String, Object> userData = input.getAttributesManager()
            .getPersistentAttributes();
    userData.put("organiser", newNote);
    userData.put("sort", "vinni");
       persistAttributes();
```